# ttyAMA0 serial port RaspberryPI3

Tags: raspberry-pi3, yocto, uart

I am not able to use ttyAMA0 serial port on the RaspberryPi3 from a cpp app when I build the image by using Yocto. If I use the original Raspbian image, on the same hw, then it works perfectly.
I followed the indication on meta-raspberrypi docs 
[docs](http://meta-raspberrypi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
by adding 
`ENABLE_UART = '1'`
and `SERIAL_CONSOLE = '115200 tty1'` ( to redirect to another tty the console )
and `MACHINE_FEATURES += " pi3-disable-bt"`
but nevertheless the RaspberryPi is not moving the UART_TX0 pin when I try sending some data to the uart. this instead works correctly with the original Raspbian image.
What should I add or modify ? it is not clear nor there is other documentation about this.

Comment: tty1 value doesn't seem correct, have you tried SERIAL_CONSOLE = "115200 ttyS0" ? You should also use double quotes in initialization, ENABLE_UART= "1" however the latter should be by default with pi3-disable-bt

Answer (score 0):

Usually the Raspberry Pi 3 has two serial ports, one via UART and the other on the GPIO pins. The first one has it's name commonly known as "ttyAMA0" the second one uses the name.

Try one of them if doesn't work you will have to look the name that it's being recognised and use it as your device name.

```
ls /dev/serial/by-id/
```

My device is a ARPI600 and when I connect it I setup my serial communication like this

```
serial.Serial("/dev/serial/by-id/usb-Silicon_Labs_CP2102_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller_0001-if00-port0", baudrate=115200, timeout=1.0)
```